# What does this for-loop do?

Tags: javascript

```
for (o.$slider.addClass("slick-dotted"), t = i("<ul />").addClass(o.options.dotsClass), e = 0; e <= o.getDotCount(); e += 1)
  t.append(i("<li />").append(o.options.customPaging.call(this, o, e)));
  
(o.$dots = t.appendTo(o.options.appendDots)), o.$dots.find("li").first().addClass("slick-active");
```

I have to modify a JS-Script from a template I downloaded. In order to do this, I first wanted to understand the script, so I know where and what I have to change. But I don't understand what these lines of code do, can anyone help?(I understand the principle of for-loops, but this one seems different and I'm a bit confused.
And yes I'm aware that you can't tell me what exactly will appear on the website, since you only have two lines of code, but I just need to know what happens with a specific class or element and I hope you can read this information from these two lines).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first step: format the script. I invite you to do this yourself.

Comment: Adding on to trincot's comment, there are loads of online formatters you could use

Answer (score 0):

Strip back the object/plugin calls, add a couple of console logs:

```
for (console.log('do this'), console.log('then this'), e = 0; e <= 10; e += 1)
  console.log.call(this, 'slider', e);
```

result is:

```
do this
then this
slider 0
slider 1
slider 2
slider 3
slider 4
slider 5
slider 6
slider 7
slider 8
slider 9
slider 10
```

It's building out `<li>`'s for the slick slider DOM

Answer (score 0):

It seems like minified code, it will therefore always be hard to read and understand. You should get the unminified version and work on that instead.

Here is the same code unminified plus the rest of surrounding function (from [GitHub](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/9c55b531245e8c866324652a353bead23f9721a0/slick/slick.js#L482)), I hope now it makes a lot more sense:

```js
    Slick.prototype.buildDots = function() {

        var _ = this,
            i, dot;

        if (_.options.dots === true && _.slideCount > _.options.slidesToShow) {

            _.$slider.addClass('slick-dotted');

            dot = $('<ul />').addClass(_.options.dotsClass);

            for (i = 0; i <= _.getDotCount(); i += 1) {
                dot.append($('<li />').append(_.options.customPaging.call(this, _, i)));
            }

            _.$dots = dot.appendTo(_.options.appendDots);

            _.$dots.find('li').first().addClass('slick-active');

        }

    };
```

It checks if the option `dots` is set and there are more slides than visible, and in this case it adds the class `slick-dotted` to the slider and creates an `<ul>` with the `dotsClass` and fills it with `<li>`s that contain the return value of the `customPaging` function. At the end, the first `<li>` gets the `slick-active` class. - I.e., it creates the dot navigation for the slides.